# UglifyJs unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, uglifyjs

I have already used this in my webpack.config.js

```
use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'es2016', 'react']
        }
      }]
```

But still I am getting error at the token **let** which I have used.

> I get that uglify doesn't understands ECMAScript-6

Now when i build my webpack with -p, i get the mentioned error, because uglify comes up there. 
Now, how can i solve this problem as I have already included babel-loader preset es2015 to convert es6 to es5.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the error text you are getting at the token *let* ?

Comment: UglifyJs failure, Unexpected token error: name (xyz) @raghav710

Comment: I have fixed the issue as described in the following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606913/unexpected-token-name-documentattributes-with-webpack-and-uglifyjs/65845893#65845893

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've said, your current version of the Uglify plugin doesn't support ES6, so you'll need to upgrade. You have a few options:

1. Upgrade to Webpack 4, which includes the new uglify plugin by default
2. If you need to stay on v3 for whatever reason, [you can follow the instructions on the docs here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/) to install the new uglify plugin and use it manually.

Comment: Upgrading to webpack 4 solved my issue, will revert back and try to find the root cause, until then thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use terser-webpack-plugin for minifying ES6 code