# Unexpected token: name (DocumentAttributes) with webpack and UglifyJs

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, uglifyjs

I am using docx 5.0.2 version for generating word document with images from the angular type script code.
using webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin. Getting this error when building the code .
**Unexpected token: name (DocumentAttributes)** with webpack and UglifyJs.
I assume Uglify is not able to minimize or beautify code related to docx library. Any suggestions from people using the docx package.

Build used to work fine before docx package added to the package.json

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is with Uglify that cannot process ES6. I solved this problem by using uglifyjs-webpack-plugin instead.

run  `npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1 --dev --save` I'm using version 1 since I'm with an older version of webpack.

then `const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');`

```
  test: /\.js($|\?)/i,
  sourceMap: true,
  uglifyOptions: {
    mangle: {
      keep_fnames: true,
    },
    compress: {
      warnings: false,
    },
    output: {
      beautify: false,
    },
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Original answer is completely valid, the problem is that Uglify can't process ES6 and it seems a lot of node_modules now aren't transpiling their code to ES5 before publishing (which makes sense, we dont live in 2015 anymore).

But the solution assumes you're on webpack4 .. for anyone else arriving here stuck for various reasons on webpack3 and `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin`:

For us, the answer was to let our webpack babel-loader transpile those node_modules. Instead of sending all node_modules through the babel loader (which isn't recommended for performance reasons), you can exclude all apart from specific packages and package name patterns like this:

`exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(react-markdown|mdast-util-.*|micromark-.*)\/).*/`